# How to display the full path in Windows 7 explorer file operation dialogue?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-transfer

I'm using the Windows 7 Explorer to copy files. During the operation, some information are displayed. However, for a reason beyond my understanding, a part of the path is displayed twice, which clutters the screen needlessly. And more importantly, the last subdirectory of the source path is *not displayed at all*.

When copying from `C:\Program Files\Some Program` to `D:\some dir\some child dir` this is displayed:

[image]

This often leads to frustration when I cannot remember which exact path was the source for an operation, in particular when there are multiple such operations in progress where the source paths are sibling directories.

Is there any way to change this behavior? I am using ClassicShell, but could not find an option for this matter.

Comment: While this doesn't necessarily answer your question, have a look at [TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy). This is a popular replacement for the Windows copier, and should display the full path, along with many other features.

Answer (score 1):

The format of the detailed info is

**Name**: filename.ext
**From**: Source_Dir (Full_Path_With_Source_Dir)
**To**: Destination_Dir (Full_Path_With_Destination_Dir)

etc.

The **Name** will always display the filename.
The **From** always displays the parent directory of the item you are copying. However, you may copy whole directories, in which case, that folder's name will not be mentioned. The reason for this is simple: directories do not hold data, so they are not really copied, they are actually recreated in the destination.

Comment: I'm not sure what these terms mean exactly - where are they from? As described, the "full paths" are sadly not really full because the leaf directory is missing. When copying from C:\X\Y\*, it is displayed as C:\X without the leaf directory Y.

Comment: They are just descriptive terms that I used. Source_Dir is **where from** you are copying. Destination_Dir is **where to** you are copying. Directories are folders, or "placeholders". If the copied item is a directory itself, **that** is the thing you are copying from source to destination, e.g. if you are copying directory "Z" from C:\X\Y (full path C:\X\Y\Z\), then the source is still C:\X\Y, becuase "Z" is the item, not the source.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the additional clarification.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a reasoning behind the decision. In my opinion, of course, it was a horrible regression compared to earlier versions of Windows, still.